# Added 20 Custom Fields. Only 10 showing in drop down

Tags: custom-field

Just like the title states. I've added around 20+ custom fields into my wordpress site and only around 10 are showing in the drop down.

The custom fields are all functioning fine on the site side, but they just aren't showing up in the drop down.
[image]

Comment: none of them happen to start with an underscore do they?  Undercores at the beginning of a key makes it remain hidden from that interface (useful for custom meta boxes)

Comment: @wilwaldon Can you provide a screenshot so we can see what you're talking about?

Comment: no underscores in the beginning, but there are underscores in the names. Example: left_title . Would that do the same thing?

Comment: @EAMann Added a screeny.

Comment: OK, now *which* dropdown are they not showing up in?  You have far more than 10 in that dropdown ... is that where they're missing or somewhere else?

Comment: Sorry, I know I have more than 10 in there. It was just a comparitive #. There are about 20 that aren't showing up in the drop down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a limit set inside the function that lists the meta data.

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-admin/includes/template.php#L512

Run a filter on `postmeta_form_limit` to increase to your desired value, eg.

```
add_filter( 'postmeta_form_limit', 'meta_limit_increase' );
function meta_limit_increase( $limit ) {
    return 50;
}
```

Hope that helps.. :)

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of things, you just have *way too many* custom fields.  I would highly recommend creating a few custom meta boxes to handle them rather than relying entirely on the dropdown menu.

There are [a few good tutorials](http://www.farinspace.com/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-meta-box/) out there, and whoever ends up maintaining the site will thank you for building a clean, easy-to-navigate UI.