# Custom fields with square brackets in the name

Tags: custom-field

I have some custom fields which I need to have square brackets inside. This would not be a problem apart from the fact that I need the end user to be able to reselect the custom field on another post but it is not visible. Any custom fields with a name with a square bracket is missing from the drop down list.

Is there any one that can help me to show the custom fields in the dropdown with a square bracket in it?

Comment: Please show us some code. Hard to imagine what your situation looks like and what/where exactly "inside" is.

Answer (score 0):

Try using character entities: `&#91;` and `&#93;` for left and right square brackets, respectively.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your responses. It seems I was just misinterpreting what was happening. It was only showing 10 custom fields, rather than excluding certain fields. The question has been answered here:

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14103/added-20-custom-fields-only-10-showing-in-drop-down